# can´t get after rebooting MySQL database and apache web server

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu

Mysql server stopped and apache2 server stopped. second one does work.

Now I used sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop and sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop

Apache2 web server works again. However mysql server still refuses to start.

I checked on the internet and I already changed the port but it´s still not working

Solving the problem can help others who have the same problem.

If anyone has suggestions please let me know. I´m looking forward to respnses.

Answer (score 0):

I think, your problem isnt a port problem, but the MySQL server cannot open the database. Maybe there are corrupted data after the reboot and it wasnt clearly shutdown. Have a look into /var/lib/mysql/. There should be an error.log.